# Chrome Extension content script runs more than once

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to open a new tab based on data I'm pulling from some fields in a table in the current page's DOM. To do that, in the background.js I get the row number as input from the user. Then I use this method:

```js
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
  file: 'contentScript.js' 
}, function() {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {parameter: rowIndex});
});
```

In contentScript.js, I have an event listener for the message which then I use the parameter that I sent to fetch all the row's relevant fields to variables which I build a URL and paste the values of the variables as parameters. Finally, I open the URL with window.open(url).

It is working, BUT when I do it the second time it opens two new tabs with the URL. The third time it opens three tabs etc.

```js
var rowIndex = prompt("What row# do you want to run? (Search row is index #1)");
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
  file: 'contentScript.js' 
}, function() {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {parameter: rowIndex});
});
```

ContentScript:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
  debugger;
  var rowIndex = message.parameter;
  var var1 = document.querySelector("#content > div > md-table-container > table > tbody > tr:nth-child("+ rowIndex +") > td:nth-child(4) > div > div > span").textContent.trim();
  var var2 = document.querySelector("#content > div > md-table-container > table > tbody > tr:nth-child("+ rowIndex +") > td:nth-child(7) > div > div").textContent.trim();
  var endDate = document.querySelector("#content > div > md-table-container > table > tbody > tr:nth-child("+ rowIndex +") > td:nth-child(15) > div > div > span").textContent.trim();
  console.log(endDate);
  var url = 'I_HIDE_THE_BASE_URL?var1='+ var1 + '&day='+endDate+'&record_type=record&var2='+ var2;
  window.open(url);
});
```

I can't figure out why it opens so many tabs.

Comment: With each call of `chrome.runtime.executeScript` you are injecting a new content script, which adds a new message listener. So the 2nd, 3rd, 4th time you inject the content script and send a message, there are 2, 3, 4 listeners responding to the message and creating a new window.

Comment: Only add the listener if (!chrome.runtime.onMessage.hasListeners())

Comment: @wOxxOm why isn't that in the documentation?

Comment: It's in https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events

Comment: @wOxxOm That works perfectly!

Can you explain why the method in the onMessage gets activated even though it the addEventListener is inside the if statement you provided? if the content script was already injected, wouldn't that mean that the code inside the if block won't be executed, hence the event won't fire? Or is it that once I add the event listener, it is there listening forever?

Comment: Each time the code is injected its functions are compiled to new objects so addListener sees a different function object which is why it's not skipped.